# Not sure how to run Where on a collection to return collection

Tags: c#, linq, .net-4.0

Let’s say I have instance of MyCollection class called Foo1. MyCollection is basically a collection of MyClass. Not sure how can I do something like below with or without a cast?

```
MyCollection Foo2 =  Foo1.Where( r => r.LastName == “SomeName”)
```

NOTE: MyCollection & MyClass are something from a 3rd party library. I probably can create extension method on it but hoping to have some easy way of doing it.

Comment: You are using the assignment operator =. A Where method expression needs to evaluate to a boolean, so you should use the comparison operator ==.

Comment: @olivehour good catch.  When I first read your comment, I thought you were talking about the first assignment operator in the statement, so for palm snow's benefit, I'll point out that you were talking about the second one.  The statement should read `MyCollection Foo2 =  Foo1.Where( r => r.LastName == “SomeName”)`.

Comment: sorry that was just a typo. Fixed now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have a new instance of `MyCollection` holding only those elements that meet the criteria, you can create a `Where` method on your class.

Or, you can rely on the linq extension method on `IEnumerable<T>` (assuming your class implements `IEnumerable<MyClass>`), and use whatever method you would normally use for populating a `MyCollection` from a sequence of `MyClass` objects.

**EDIT**

Example of linq extension method approach:

- ensure that `MyCollection` implements `IEnumerable<MyClass>`
- ensure that `MyCollection` has a constructor that accepts an `IEnumerable<MyClass>`
- include `#using System.Linq;`
- example statement: `MyCollection Foo2 = new MyCollection(Foo1.Where( r => r.LastName == “SomeName”))`;

**EDIT EDIT**

I see now that MyClass and MyCollection are third-party types.  I had assumed from the "my" bit that you were designing them yourself.

The `MyCollection` type almost certainly implements `IEnumerable<MyClass>` -- if it doesn't, it may implement the non-generic `IEnumerable`.  In that case, you can use the `Cast<T>` extension method.  If it implements neither interface, the third-party library is somewhat lacking.

Comment: Can you provide an example of linq extension method approach?

Comment: @palmsnow I added an example.

Answer (score 3):

You can implement `IEnumerable<MyClass>` and in implementation just enumerate over internal collection. This automatically brings up all LINQ-to-objects extension methods ([Enumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345746.aspx) class methods).

```
public class MyCollection : IEnumerable<MyClass>
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as MyCollection implements IEnumerable or IQueryable, the Where method will work, and will return a subset of matching elements. That is, elements with LastName == "SomeProperty".

The cast should not be necessary as long as MyCollection implements `IEnumerable<MyClass>` or `IQueryable<MyClass>`.